# optimizing a Slow MySQL query using EXPLAIN output

Tags: mysql, optimization, explain

The following query took 6.6 seconds to run, and yielded 26 rows.

EXPLAIN result is two SIMPLE queries of type 'ref', using keys, scanning 23 and 48 rows.

Table f has 1000 rows and table m has 42000 rows.

```
seltype table type keys                 key                 keylen  ref             rows filtered extra

SIMPLE  f     ref  PRIMARY,             forum_site_id       4       const           23   100.00   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
                   forum_site_id,
                   forums_flag_list_new_posts

SIMPLE  m     ref  forum_msg_forum_id,  forum_msg_forum_id  5       locali_db.f.id  48   100.00   Using where
                   forum_msg_status,
                   forum_msg_date
```

Here is the query (quite a simple one):

```
SELECT

    m.id AS msg_id,
    m.public_id AS msg_public_id,
       more fileds of this table ...

    f.id AS forum_id,
    f.public_id AS forum_public_id,
       more fileds of this table ...

FROM

    forum_msgs m
    INNER JOIN forums f ON
        m.forum_id = f.id

WHERE

    f.site_id = 19
    AND f.flag_list_new_posts = 1

    AND m.msg_date >= 1434803744
    AND m.status <> 11

ORDER BY
    m.msg_date DESC

LIMIT 
    100
```

All fields in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses are of type INTEGER and are defined as INDEX. The field forum_id is defined as FOREIGN KEY.

I would be happy to find out what may be causing the outrageous performance :)

Comment: The Using where on the second table should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database was running on RDS with pretty high QPS (spikes up to 200). On average that caused 50 IOP/s to disk. Changing instance storage type from magnetic to Generic SSD solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically:

```
SELECT m.*, f.*
FROM forum_msgs m INNER JOIN
     forums f
     ON m.forum_id = f.id
WHERE f.site_id = 19 AND
      f.flag_list_new_posts = 1 AND
      m.msg_date >= 1434803744 AND
      m.status <> 11
ORDER BY m.msg_date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This suggests the following indexes:  `forums(site_id, flag_list_new_posts, id)` and `forum_msgs(forum_id, msg_date, status)`.

I don't think there is a way to get around a file sort for the `order by`.

Comment: There is no advantages in having `msg_date` in the index twice.

Comment: @RickJames . . . I fixed that index.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(msg_date)
```

*Might* trick the optimizer into starting with `m` and avoiding the sort for the `ORDER BY`.

(*Please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when asking questions performance questions.)

But the sort is not the costly part.  The costly part is probably the random fetches into `m`.  Apparently the cache is cold.

The `EXPLAIN` estimates about 1000 reads (23*48), but that could be severely under/overestimated.  If `m` was not well cached, that could be 1000 disk hits, which could easily take 6.6 seconds.

If you are using InnoDB, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE of 'forum_msgs' lists the following indexes:

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_public_id` (`public_id`),
  KEY `forum_msg_forum_id` (`forum_id`),
  KEY `forum_msg_status` (`status`),
  KEY `forum_msg_date` (`msg_date`),
  KEY `forum_msg_display_number` (`display_number`),
  KEY `forum_msg_site_id` (`site_id`),
  KEY `forum_msgs_num_clicks` (`num_clicks`),
  KEY `forum_msgs_parent_id` (`parent_id`)

Comment: What engine are you using?  What datatype is `public_id`?  What about `f`?